# Android device showing up as two devices (offline and device) in ADB

Tags: adb

Connecting my device to my PC and checking for connected device show the same device twice.

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Minimal ADB and Fastboot>adb devices
List of devices attached
21e8ed64090d7ece        offline
21e8ed64090d7ece        device
```

<sup>[Original screenshot of ADB indicating device as both connected and offline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYAxp.png)</sup>

Running any command results in ADB spitting out an error:

`error: more than one device/emulator`

What do I do?

Device: Samsung S9 (SM-G960F) (starlte) (Exynos) 
Android version: 12 (Arrow OS) 
Build number: SQ1D.220205.004

Comment: adb kill-server

Answer (score 0):

One of these solutions must work

1. `adb kill-server` then trying adb commands again
2. `adb kill-server` then turn ON and OFF usb debugging under dev options and trying adb commands again
3. Possible solution 1 and 2 but do a reboot too
4. **Trying a different USB port in your computer**
5. Trying a different data cable